# How will the key features of HTML5 work, contrast to HTML4?

Tags: html, html4

Please write code.
How will HTML5 code differ from HTML4?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read

**[HTML 5 differences from HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-diff-20090825/)**

Comment: Though no codes which the OP requested, still a good reference. +1

Comment: It would probably be better to link to the latest version of that document, located here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/

Comment: Is there a difference between those two documents?

Comment: As far as code samples are concerned I don't think those will fit in this posting.

Comment: @okw: there is code on the linked page...

Comment: @pulse: Not currently, but the link I provided in my comment will always point to the most recent version of that document.

Answer (score 6):

One example borrowed from: [A List Apart - A Preview of HTML 5](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/previewofhtml5):

**HTML 4:**

```
<body>
  <div id="header">...</div>
  <div id="nav">...</div>
  <div class="article">
    <div class="section">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="aside">...</div>
  <div id="footer">...</div>
</body>
```

**HTML 5 adds new elements to specifically identify each of these common constructs:**

```
<body>
  <header>...</header>
  <nav>...</nav>
  <article>
    <section>
      ...
    </section>
  </article>
  <aside>...</aside>
  <footer>...</footer>
</body>
```

These elements are summarized as follows:

- **section**: A part or chapter in a book, a section in a chapter, or essentially anything that has its own heading.
- **header**: The page header shown on the page; not the same as the head element.
- **footer**: The page footer where the fine print goes; the signature in an e-mail message.
- **nav**: A collection of links to other pages.
- **article**: An independent entry in a blog, magazine, compendium, and so forth.
- **aside**: For content that is tangentially related to the content around it, and is typically useful for marking up sidebar

Answer (score 5):

Compare these two files:

- http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/examples/blog-original.html (XHTML 1.0 Strict)
- http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/examples/blog-html5.html (HTML5)

A detailed explanation can be found in chapter 3 of [Dive Into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/), titled [“What Does It All Mean?”](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/semantics.html).

Answer (score 4):

To start with one of the possible HTML 4 doctypes are as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

And the HTML5 doctype is this:

```
<!doctype html>
```

The w3 have an [article on the differences between the two specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-diff-20090825/#doctype), lets remember that the HTML5 specification is not finalised yet, and is subject to change.

Comment: yea, considering HTML4 was conceived in 97, we still have compatility issues. HTML5 better be a good one.